# Adding task.delay tasks causing the proceeding code to not execute

Tags: vb.net, list, asynchronous, task

I am testing the code below, and for some reason, i never get to see "test2" outputted. Anyone know why? 
What it should do is run a set of tasks, in a delay form, and then should output the test2, but this is not happening.

```
    Console.WriteLine("test1")
    Dim tasks As IEnumerable(Of Task(Of Integer)) = {Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(Function() 3), Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(Function() 1), Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(Function() 2), Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(Function() 5), Task.Delay(4000).ContinueWith(Function() 4)}
    Console.WriteLine("test2")
```

Comment: just to add, i am trying to follow the example at the bottom of this page http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/08/02/processing-tasks-as-they-complete.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Task(Of Integer)` throws an invalid cast exception. You can simply write this:

```
Dim tasks As IEnumerable(Of Task) = {
    Task.Delay(3000).ContinueWith(Function() 3),
    Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(Function() 1),
    Task.Delay(2000).ContinueWith(Function() 2),
    Task.Delay(5000).ContinueWith(Function() 5),
    Task.Delay(4000).ContinueWith(Function() 4)
}
```

Comment: How could i do it if i wanted to return a task of integer tho?

Comment: @user984314 You don't have a list of `Task(Of Integer)`. ContinueWith returns a Task so you have a list of tasks.